# Give a style to show full buttons on AlertController when it has 2 inputs

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I use [AlertController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/) with 2 input boxes. Due to that, I can see only half of the buttons. So how can I style it to show full buttons when there is a keypad is opened on the device?

I have tried this: But it is never applied on runtime.

*1.scss*

```
   .alert-button-group {
        margin-top: -25px !important;
    }
```

[image]

.ts

```
myAlert(){

const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: this.enterApiKeyText,
      inputs: [
        {
          name: 'apiKey',
          placeholder: this.apiKey
        },
        {
          name: 'apiName',
          placeholder: this.apiName
        },
      ],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          handler: data => {
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Save',
          handler: (data) => {           

            }
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    alert.present();
}
```

*.html*

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-3 tappable (click)="myAlert()">
      <button ion-fab mini>
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
```

Comment: With a 30k reputation, I would hope you would know now to provide a little more detail in your question such as code, what you have tried, etc.. This is why i downvoted your questions. With that being said, it looks like need to add an `overflow: hidden` and possibly `height: auto` to the `.alert-wrapper` class.

Comment: also I strongly discourage using negative margin properties. this is really a hack and is probably exacerbating your problem.

Comment: Your solution is also not working. @SandraWillford

Comment: well without a reproducable code block, stackblitz, codepen or something to work with that doesn't invlove a picture it was just a guess :)

Comment: This requires a `device`. Stackbltz won't work. I would expect an answer from the person who had this problem earlier. That is why I did not add code. @SandraWillford

Comment: @SandraWillford I would not discourage using negative margins in general, since there are actually situations, where you'll need it. You should only avoid them if you try to "fix" something, that's broken somewhere else. But if you want that image to stick out a little bit? Why bot using a negative margin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Doc [is here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/alert/AlertController/#sass-variables).

*variables.scss*

```
$alert-md-message-padding-bottom:0;
$alert-ios-message-padding-bottom:0;
```

Comment: Link to New Docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert#controller